# Channel Form CSS?

Tags: channel-form, css

This might be a simple question, but with Channel Forms, the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html#id13) says:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

I see a channel_form.css file in themes>cp_themes>default>css, but I'm wondering: how does Channel Form see that file? Or am I supposed to copy the file, rename, and place in css folder elsewhere? I guess I'm not getting how this "path" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about location of the ee channel form css in a default ee install. The {path=css/_ee_channel_form_css} variable will automatically be replaced when the template is parsed and point to the correct css. Just use:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

If you need to you can always override parts of it with inline css, other css loaded after, or through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug for EE3.  View temporary fix here: 
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21711/channel-form-css-meta-not-working